# Probabilistic Kleene's recursión theorem

Tags: probability, measure-theory, computability, fixed-points

Kleene's recursion theorem states that for every total computable function $f$ there is an index $e$ such that $$\phi_{f(e)} = \phi_e,$$ where $\phi_n$ is a valid enumeration of the partial computable functions. Call such an $e$ a *fixed point* of $f$.

In Cutland's *Computability*, a question is proposed: would a chimpanzee sending each $n$ to a random $f(n)$ leave some $e$ fixed?

Although the question is mainly philosophical, there is a purely mathematical version:

> If a random total function $f : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ is chosen, what is the probability that $f$ does *not* have fixed points in the above sense?

I conjecture that the measure of that set is going to be zero, so the particular probability measure used is not going to be important.

---

**My reasons for the conjecture**. I find it rather unlikely that computable functions all share a property that few non-computable functions share (except for properties that clearly have to do with $f$ being computable).

In fact, all the functions in Turing degrees below $\emptyset'$ are known to have this property, not only computable functions. (Edit: only the recursively enumerable degrees below it)

Nevertheless, it also appears that, for every $e$, almost no function fixes $e$, and so many, many functions won't have fixed points. This is counter evidence for my conjecture.

This question is probably simple, but I don't have much background in measure theory.

Comment: "In fact, all the functions in Turing degrees below $\emptyset'$ are known to have this property, not only the computable ones." This is not true: it's only the **c.e.** Turing degrees $<_T\emptyset'$ which are fixed-point-free, and not every degree below $\emptyset'$ is c.e. In particular, there are *low* (so much weaker than $\emptyset'$) fixed-point-free functions.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected it

Comment: How exactly are you choosing a ‘random’ function $\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$? What is the probability measure?

Comment: @FShrike So according to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159355/measure-on-baire-space) I think the concrete measure does not matter, since I just want to know if the probability is $0$ or $1$. If I understand the answer correctly, only the $\sigma$-algebra matters for that, and there is a natural one.